# Meta og tags don't work using Next.js even facebook debugger

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using React + NextJS (both latest version) (not using redux etc. .)

I need to change meta tags' contents dynamically

When I render page and observe through chrome Dev tools, Meta Tags are created successfully
But It does not work when I provide url on Slack, FB etc ..
Also Facebook OpenGraph debugger cannot check my og tags

Need some help

Here's my code

[id].jsx >

```
  const Main = () => {
....

    return (
    <>
        <MetaSEO
            title={response.data.seo ? response.data.seo['page-title'] : SEOSheet.seo.title}
            keywords={response.data.seo ? response.data.seo.keywords : SEOSheet.seo.keywords}
            description={response.data.seo ? response.data.seo.description : SEOSheet.seo.description}
            ogType={SEOSheet.seo['sns-type']}
            ogTitle={response.data.seo ? response.data.seo['sns-title'] : SEOSheet.seo['sns-title']}
            ogDescription={response.data.seo ? response.data.seo['sns-description'] : SEOSheet.seo['sns-description']}
            ogImage={SEOSheet.seo['sns-image']}
            ogUrl={SEOSheet.seo['sns-url']}
            indexing="all"
          />
.......
    </>
    );
}
```

MetaSEO.jsx >

```
    import Head from 'next/head';

const MetaSEO = ({
  title, keywords, description, ogTitle, ogDescription, ogImage, ogUrl, indexing
}) => (
  <Head>
    <title>{title}</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
    <meta name="description" content={description} />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content={ogTitle} />
    <meta property="og:description" content={ogDescription} />
    <meta property="og:image" content={ogImage} />
    <meta property="og:url" content={ogUrl} />
    <meta name="robots" content={indexing} />
  </Head>
);

export default MetaSEO;
```

Efforts to solve I did ->
-Used NextSEO
-Added Meta Tags at all pages
-Used getInitialProps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the data using `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` then pass it via props to the component in order to render meta tags correctly, you can verify it using `View Source` and not using `Dev Tools`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! I am understanding getServerSideProps is part of getInitialProps. But getInitialProps did not work. Could it can be a problem of document.jsx or app.jsx?

Comment: could you post the result of the `View Source`

Comment: There was nothing when I view source --- solved --- there was some codes that blocks  component rendering (such as 'return false')

Answer (score 0):

--- solved --- there was some codes that blocks component rendering (such as 'return false')